# What's the time complexity of T(n) = n⋅log(n) + T(n-1)?

Tags: complexity-theory

Assume that `T(n) = n⋅log(n) + T(n-1)`, then what's the time complexity of `T(n)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
T(n) = n log n + (n-1) log (n-1) + ... + 1 log 1 + T(0)
     < n log n + (n-1) log n + ... 1 log n + T(0)
     = ( n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1) log n + T(0)
     = n(n+1)/2 ⋅ log n + T(0)
```

So it is in `O(n² log n)`, if `T(0)` is also in `O(n² log n)`.

Other way:

```
T(n) = n log n + (n-1) log (n-1) + ... + 1 log 1 + T(0)
     < n log n + n log (n-1) + ... + n log 1 + T(0)
     = n (log n + log (n-1) + ... + log 1) + T(0)
     = n log (n!) + T(0)
     < n log (nⁿ) + T(0)
     = n ⋅ n ⋅ log n + T(0)
     = n² log n
```

**Edit:**
You can also see a lower bound by the same way:

```
T(n) = n log n + (n-1) log (n-1) + ... + 1 log 1 + T(0)
     > n log n/2 + (n-1) log n/2 + ... + n/2 log n/2 + (n/2-1) log 1 + ... 1 log 1 + T(0)
     = ( n(n+1)/2-n/4(n/2+1) ) log n/2 + T(0)
     = (3/8 n² + 1/4 n) log n/2 + T(0)
     = (3/8 n² + 1/4 n) log n - (3/8 n² + 1/4 n) log 2
     = 3/8 n² log n + 1/4 n log n - (3/8 n² + 1/4 n) log 2
```

So `T(n)` is in `Ω(n² log n)`.

Together you get `Θ(n² log n)` (as long as `T(0)` is in `O(n² log n)`)

Answer (score 2):

This expands to

```
T(n) = T(0) + 1⋅log(1) + 2⋅log(2) + ... + (n-1)⋅log (n-1) + n⋅log(n)
```

which

`≈ ∫n⋅log(n) dn = (n²/2)⋅log(n)−n²/4 = O(n²⋅logn)`

(approximation using integral)

Comment: Just started reading the MIT Introduction to Algorithms text :)

Comment: I think it should be: T(0) + 1log 1 + 2log 2 + ... + (n-1)log (n - 1) + nlog n

Comment: Yup you're right actually

Comment: Updated answer, hopefully that is right

Comment: Why T(0) + 1log 1 + 2log 2 + ... + (n-1)log (n - 1) + nlog n = n!log(n!) ?

Comment: @injoy This would be `n log (n!)` and this is also in `O(n^2 log n)`.

Answer (score -1):

Express T(n) as a sum, and then the solution follows immediately.

Comment: I tried, and it didn't work.